# Parse a file to count the number of day occurrence

Tags: shell, awk

I've have the following input file (call it `log`).

```
2012-02-10 11:00:44.211 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:44.598 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:45.510 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:45.891 connection closed_to host
2012-02-10 11:00:46.111 connection closed_to host
```

I want to be able to count the number of line for each minute. For example, I would like to obtain the output below:

```
2012-02-10 11:00 connection closed to host 5
```

Comment: As written this question makes very little sense.  Most people reading it will NOT see any other questions you may have posted.  Please edit this to be a stand-alone question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given input file has 5 matches at `11:00` not 4 and there are not matches at `11:01` but ignoring that:

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{a[$1" "$2":"$3" "$5" "$6" "$7]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' log
2012-02-10 11:00 connection closed_to host 5
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was just an example. Thanks!